# Move mediawiki TOC to sidebar

Tags: javascript, php, html, mediawiki

I've been trying to find a method on moving the TOC in MediaWiki to the sidebar or any location really that I want it outside of the main content but with no success.

The simplest looking solution brought up the following but it doesn't seem to actually move the TOC.

```
<div id="toc_sidebar_holder"> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var toc = document.getElementById('toc');
    var toc_holder = document.getElementById('toc_sidebar_holder');
    if(toc && toc_holder){
        toc.parentNode.removeChild(toc);
        toc_holder.appendChild(toc);
        }
</script>
```

Then here is what the HTML looks like for the TOC currently.

```
<table id="toc" class="toc"><tr><td><div id="toctitle"><h2>Contents</h2></div>
    <ul>
      <li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-1"><a href="#Cats"><span class="tocnumber">1</span> <span class="toctext">Cats</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-2"><a href="#Type"><span class="tocnumber">1.1</span> <span class="toctext">Type</span></a></li>
          <li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-3"><a href="#Meows"><span class="tocnumber">1.2</span> <span class="toctext">Meows</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-4"><a href="#Dogs"><span class="tocnumber">2</span> <span class="toctext">Dogs</span></a>
        <ul>
        <li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-5"><a href="#Woof"><span class="tocnumber">2.1</span> <span class="toctext">Woof</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</td></tr></table>
```

Really looking for a solution or figuring out how to get the function above to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That script looks fine, but if you you test it, you might notice that `toc` is not assigned.

Put the script at the bottom of your skin, so it is executed when both elements are already available.