# mediawiki: have TOC / page sections displayed in the sidebar

Tags: mediawiki

one might assume that this would be quite a common question, but I couldn't find any helpful answers yet, so I'll ask. I have to add that I find the whole structure of mediawiki and also their help pages very confusing.
I'm not expecting an exact answer, I'll also be grateful for resources that will help me understand just how mediawiki is structured.

OK, so:

I want to set up a Wiki for personal uses, and I'm trying to get the sidebar customized to my needs, especially I want to have the section headings (that would be level 2 to, say, 4 headings) of the page that is currently viewed displayed in the sidebar (as anchors, I guess).
In other words, have the table of contents not on the top of the body / content part, but on the left hand side in the sidebar.

I have somewhat edited MediaWiki:Sidebar and could get rid of some stuff that I don't really need, but I just can't find a way to get a table of contents there.

Do I need an extension or is this possible with MWs standard functions?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716918/move-mediawiki-toc-to-sidebar), but I would prefer not to edit the html or js myself and rather just edit MediaWiki:Sidebar if that is possible at all.

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a build in way to do that. I don't know any extension, which actually provides such a feature. But there is a JavaScript, written by a MediaWiki developer, which does, I assume, what you're looking for:

https://github.com/prtksxna/persistent-toc

It will show all ToC levels at the left side, if the first visible area of the page goes out of the viewport (and the top ToC box isn't visible anymore). It would maybe not a big deal to limit the ToC to level 2-4. You could install this script via your MediaWiki:Common.js, your user specific js (like I did for WMF [projects][1] or you create a new extension, which adds the script and the css to your page.

[1]: https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Florianschmidtwelzow/global.js projects

Comment: Hi Florian. Thanks very much for your answer. Guess my initial post was somewhat unspecific. Meanwhile I've better understood what the post that I've linked to in my first post does, and managed to use it somewhat satisfyingly.  I also checked out the link you proposed, but (I forgot to mention that) with 1.19 it does not work (simply does nothing). So I took the script and placed the TOC above the portals that get rendered in the panel and made it position:fixed. With some more customization like scrollbar for long TOC it's now pretty close to what I wanted. Thanks again. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The new Vector (2022) skin does it automatically, but you have to enable it manually in your Wikimedia installation. Just go to **Special:Preferences** and switch from **Vector legacy (2010)** (the default one) to **Vector (2022)**. Afterward, you will see the **move to sidebar** option at the top of the TOC on your wiki pages.